# how to make the tabs just like the one in stackoverflow

Tags: html, css

How do i make that effect with the tabs (i.e. the tabbed 'active', 'featured', 'hot', 'week', 'month')  using just html and css? i tried copying the css but it didn't work. can anyone help or lead me to a tutorial just like this? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need:

- 5 divs, with .tab class.
- .tab-container, a css class for the container div, that needs a botoom border, this will contain tabs.
- .tab css class, that contains basic block features, some `color:`, `padding:`, and `margin:`, also it needs to `float: left`, so all the divs with that class float to the left of the container.
- .active css class, that have a left, top and right border, and maybe some different color, if you want so.
- since .tab elements will be links, and `<a>` elements are `inline` by default, you need to specify `display: block` css for `.tab` as well.

Now the layout:

- a container div.tab-container
- child `a.tab` elements.

Try with that here: http://jsfiddle.net/ click save and comment with the saved link you have, or edit your question with the css/html you wrote based on the mini-tutorial above.

Comment: 5 is meant as example, since we got 5 tabs here on SO.

Comment: this answer is not complete, the problem is that active/hover tab has bottom border, in original menu there is no bottom border.

Answer (score 0):

I will prefer to do the tabs with `ul` and `li` inside a `div` container with id `#tabcontainer`

and in your css you will have some:

### CSS:

```
#tabcontainer ul li {
 // properties to items
}

#tabcontainer ul li a {
 // properties for links
}

#tabcontainer ul li a:hover {
 // properties for hover links
}

#tabcontainer ul li .active {
 // properties for active item
}
```

### HTML:

```
<div id="tabcontainer">
      <ul>
          <li class="active"><a id="item" href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a id="item" href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a id="item" href="#">Link 3</a></li>
          <li><a id="item" href="#">Link 4</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

In the `li` tags in your server side language you will set a variable to which link is already active as you see the address in the address bar changes to `?tab=hot` when you click `hot`